Examples of bounded EM blueprints?
Following Jech's notation, for each Ehrenfeucht-Mostowski blueprint $\Sigma$ there is up to isomorphism a unique model with $\alpha$ many indiscernibles whose Skolem hull is equal to the whole model, and we call this the $(\Sigma,\alpha)$-model. $0^\sharp$ is the unique EM blueprint $\Sigma$ that satisfies:

every $(\Sigma,\alpha)$-model is well-founded;
for any limit $\alpha$, the indiscernibles of the $(\Sigma,\alpha)$-model are unbounded in the ordinals of the model;
for any $\alpha>\omega$, in the $(\Sigma,\alpha)$-model the first $\omega$ many indiscernibles are unbounded below the $\omega$-th indiscernible. Edit: actually this is formally weaker than the usual definition that the hull of $\{i_n:n<\omega\}$ contains all ordinals below $i_\omega$. So another question is whether this is strictly weaker...

It turns out if there is an EM blueprint satisfying 1 then there is one satisfying all three. I think I understand why 3 can fail in general. For example, if $(i_n:n<\omega)$ are indiscernibles then so are $(i_n+\omega:n<\omega)$. But I am struggling to find a counterexample to 2.
Question: What is an example of a well-founded EM blueprint that doesn't satisfy 2? For a candidate, is it true that if $I=\{i_\xi:\xi<\alpha\}$ are indiscernibles for $L_\gamma$ and $Hull^{L_{\gamma}}(I)=L_{\gamma}$, then they are also indiscernibles for $L_{\gamma+\omega}$ and $Hull^{L_{\gamma+\omega}}(I)=L_{\gamma+\omega}$? Is this at least possible?
